# Euler's totient function in C

Tags: c, loops, primes

For a natural number n, Euler's totient function is defined as the number of natural numbers in the set `{1,...n}` that are relatively prime with `n`. I have to write a program in C language so that for the input `n` the output is the Euler's totient function of `n`. 
This was my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void) {

int n,k;

scanf("%d", &n);

for (k=1; k<n; k++) {
  if(n%k !=0) 

  printf("%d\n", k);

  }

return 0;

}
```

Later I realized that this should also give me `1` as output for every `n`,  so I thought I could just add this before `return 0`:

```
if(k=1) printf("1");
```

But this doesn't seem very nice...How can I write this program more intelligently?

Comment: `if(k=1)` ==> `if(k==1)`. But you will need a GCD function [please read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).

Comment: `if(n%k !=0)` This is not the way to check if k is co-prime to n. Example: n=16 and k = 12.

Comment: see [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Euler's totient function counts the positive integers up to a given integer n that are relatively prime to n* [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function)

You can calculate relative prime, or coprime, as follows:

```
int coprime(int a, int b)
{
    while(b)
    {
        a %= b;

        //swap a & b
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Calculate Euler's Totient as:

```
int phi(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    int k;
    for(k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        result += coprime(k, n) == 1;
    return result;
}
```

Testing:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", i, phi(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Result (compare with [other](http://primefan.tripod.com/Phi500.html) results)

> ```
> 1 1
> 2 1
> 3 2
> 4 2
> 5 4
> 6 2
> 7 6
> 8 4
> 9 6
> ```